# Aiogram RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread of the main interpreter

Tags: python, flask, aiogram

I am writing aiogram bot and minimal api using Flask in one project
project perfectly works on Windows machine but throws error on ubuntu 22.04.3
I am using python version 3.12.1
Here is the error:

```
ValueError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread of the main interpreter

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1010, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/var/www/Bots/FinshaDocBot/app.py", line 18, in <lambda>
    bot_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: asyncio.run(main()))
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 684, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/www/Bots/FinshaDocBot/app.py", line 44, in main
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 510, in start_polling
    loop.add_signal_handler(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 107, in add_signal_handler
    raise RuntimeError(str(exc))
RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread of the main interpreter
```

here is my app.py file

```
import json
import threading
from flask import Flask
from loader import dp,bot
from aiogram.types.bot_command_scope_all_private_chats import BotCommandScopeAllPrivateChats
import asyncio
from utils.notify_admins import start,shutdown
from utils.set_botcommands import commands
# Info
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

import handlers
import logging
import sys
from models import doctor
app = Flask(__name__)

bot_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: asyncio.run(main()))
bot_thread.daemon = True
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    data = request.json
    tg_id = doctor.getdoctorbyemail(data['email'])
    if (tg_id):
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(bot.send_message(text=f"sizga {data['price']} sum kashback tushdi",chat_id=tg_id), loop=loop)
        
    return {"message":"success"}


def run_api():
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app=app,host="0.0.0.0",port=8080)

async def main():
    try:
        global loop
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
        await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
        await bot.set_my_commands(commands=commands,scope=BotCommandScopeAllPrivateChats(type='all_private_chats'))
        dp.startup.register(start)
        dp.shutdown.register(shutdown)
        await dp.start_polling(bot)
    finally:
        await bot.session.close()
        
        
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    bot_thread.start()
    run_api()
```

error is related to my main method 44-th line `await bot.set_my_commands(commands=commands,scope=BotCommandScopeAllPrivateChats(type='all_private_chats'))`

tried to use on windows on code worked
but error keeps on ubuntu 22.04.3